# call on .load in not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page `xyz.jsp` which having a script on page load and its working fine.

```
  function loginRegOverlay() {
           $("#hiddenLoginButton").click();
         };
```

but if i am calling this page on `abc.jsp` on jquery `.load` page is rendering but

```
$("#hiddenLoginButton").click(); is not working.
```

dont know the reason why its not coming.

please tell me that its working onload of xyz.jsp but if i calling that page on abc.jsp it not working

Adding code which is in abc.jsp:

```
 function newstyle(){
          $("#test").load("xyz.jsp");
      };
```

so, newstyle calling onload on abc.HTML rendering fine  but

```
function loginRegOverlay() {
       $("#hiddenLoginButton").click();
    };
```

which is in xyz.jsp not working fine if i am calling that on abc.jsp..i hope its clear now.

Comment: if you could post some rendered html too.

Comment: or if you could tell us how are you calling above given function.

Comment: where do you call your loginRegOverlay()? inside a $.ready?

Answer (score 0):

Try with .**trigger** like

```
$("#hiddenLoginButton").trigger('click');
```

and we assumed that you have called the function loginRegOverlay() on page load

AND I have noticed that **you wrote code in xyz.jsp and you want to trigger it on abc.jsp** then include that xyz.jsp at abc.jsp

```
inlcude('xyz.jsp');
```

and plz makesure that those buttons ids are unique bec xyz is loads on abc and due to duplicate in ids they wont work,you can give them same class and fire it as once

Comment: that xyz.jsp also coming through .load in abc.jsp

Comment: Then you need to change the id's of that buttons and call them individually,bec duplicate ids are not allowed in jquery

Comment: #hiddenLoginButton its only in xyz.jsp not in abc.jsp

Comment: So what "please tell me that its working onload of xyz.jsp but if i calling that page on abc.jsp it not working" means..??

Comment: see if i am loading xyz.jsp individually its working fine but if i am calling this xyz.jsp on abc.jsp its not working

Comment: that is iam saying,if u load xyz it is working that means one id 'hiddenLoginButton' is there in xyz,and if u call xyz on abc then 2 ids will be there,causes duplicate

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30378/discussion-between-sachin-rawal-and-gautam3164)

Answer (score 0):

`.load()` is an ajax request so if you are loading elements from other page then direct binding of events to the element won't work. So workaround to this is **event delegation** which you have to delegate the event to the existing parent item which is loading the html from other page.

```
$(document).find('#hiddenLoginButton').click();
```

You can delegate it to the closest parent which was available at the time of page load:

```
$('#ID or .Class of the parent item').find('#hiddenLoginButton').click();
```

like:

```
$('#wrapper').find('#hiddenLoginButton').click();
```

*side note:*

*if you are able to post some rendered html then that would be much better to see what is going on and what will be suggested to overcome this.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use .live or .on method for event delegation

```
$("#hiddenLoginButton").live('click', function(){});
```